# how to check if validationgroup passed?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

Currently working with UserControls.

Have this button :

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="btn btn-active" ValidationGroup="MyValidationGroup" OnClick="BtnSaveClick">
```

I inherited this code from my team mates.

Recently i discovered that if button is clicked multiple times, it duplicates the record.

I tried to add

```
btnSave.ClientEnabled = false;
```

and

```
btnSave.Enabled = false;
```

into the code behind, but it's not preventing from duplicating the records.

How to check if validation group passed (successfully) into jquery or javascript, than disable the button on the front end ?

Any idea ?

Comment: If you do not want duplicates, why not check them at the database level? Disabling a button will help with double clicking. But you will still get the same result if a user presses `F5` or reloads the page as new and then presses the button again.

Comment: Yes. This thing should that way. Add your comment as an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well simply use

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" class="btn btn-active" OnClick="btnSave_Click" ValidationGroup="validation" Text="Save" OnClientClick="if (!Page_ClientValidate()){ return false; } this.disabled = true; this.value = 'Saving...';"
                                        UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
```

This code snippet will disable your button and doesn't allow use to click multiple times until click event executing its code
Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 1):

you can do this  $(document).ready(function(){

```
$('#ctl00_MainContent_btnSave')
  .attr("onclick", null)
  .removeAttr("onclick")
  .click(function() {         
  // To validate you form using Validation group.
   if (typeof (Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') {
                Page_ClientValidate("ValidationGroup");
                if (Page_IsValid == true) {
                    alert('the form is valid');
                }
            } else {
                if ($(this).valid()) {
                    alert('the form is valid');
                }
            }               

        //Disable button before page posting back
        WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions($(this).attr("name"), "", true, "", "", false, false));
    });
```

});

Comment: Yes but what will happen if form is invalid ?

Comment: Actually i found a method into code behind for checking if form is valid. Is it possible to make ajax call or something to check if form is valid ?

Comment: Yes you can call a javascript function using Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"CallMyFunction","MyFunction()",true); to disable button.

Comment: If this is loaded on document ready, it will remove onclick function right ??

Comment: I'm newbie to these UserControls. Sorry.

Comment: No it will not remove click function.

Comment: Page_ClientValidate is not defined. What should i use for this ?

Comment: Do you use Validation group?

Comment: Yes. My validation group.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want duplicates, why not check them at the database level? Disabling a button will help with double clicking. But you will still get the same result if a user presses F5 or reloads the page as new and then presses the button again.

For MS SQL you could do something like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT column FROM table WHERE (column = @myVar))
    INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES (@myVar)
```

Or you could also place a constraint on the column

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_column UNIQUE (column)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. When i used code @Shayan Hafeez provided, compiler thrown an exception.

```
The server tag is not well formed.
```

Than, i removed OnClientClick from the button and insert this code into code-behind :

```
btnSave.ClientSideEvents.Click = "if (!Page_ClientValidate()){ return false; } this.disabled = true; this.value = 'Saving...';";
```

It works fine now.

Comment: Well i dont know because the code have given to you is working properly for me i think you have missed some " or something but glad to know you have found the solutoin and it helps you :)